# illegal character in xml document

Tags: .net, xml

I have a program that is generating Xml Files from data out of a database. In short code it does the following:

```
string dsn = "a db connection string";
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dsn)) {
    con.Open();
    string sql = "select id as Id, comment as Comment from Test where ... ";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("EXPORT");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "Test");
        d.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());
    }
}
d.Save(@"c:\test.xml");
```

When I have a look at the xml file it contains the invalid character & # x 1 A ;

```
<EXPORT>
  <Test>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Comment> Keyboard NB&#x1A;5 linked</Comment>
  </Test>
</EXPORT>
```

This xml file cannot be opened by firefox browser saying invalid character ...

That Entity is reserved in ISO 8859-1 and CP1252 and should not be rendered by browsers. But why does XmlDocument output xml that cannot be parsed as valid - or is it a valid xml document that just cannot be parsed by Browsers or imported by Excel and so on ...
Is there a easy way of getting rid of that reserved 'invalid characters' or encoding them in a way that Browsers do not have a Problem with it?

Many thanks for your opinion and tipps

Comment: I've had the exact same problem with the various XML methods for the System.Data objects. I'm not sure what else those methods would do though. Their alternative are to strip out the characters or throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all characters are representable in XML.

In XML 1.0, none of the characters with values less than 0x20 can be used, except for TAB (0x09), LF (0x0A) and CR (0x0D).

In XML 1.1, just about anything except NUL (0x00) can be used.

If you have the option to use XML 1.1, **and** the receiving program supports XML 1.1 (not many do), then you can escape the 0x1A as `&#26;` or `&#x1A;`.

Wrapping it in `CDATA` is not a solution either; `CDATA` is just a convenience for escaping groups of characters differently than the standard &-mechanism.

Otherwise, you will need to remove it prior to serializing.

Comment: sorry for answering quite late to that old question - I removed the characters before serializing ... Thx

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this a few times when creating/manipulating XML from SQL data.

> But why does XmlDocument output xml that cannot be parsed as valid - or is it a valid xml document that just cannot be parsed by Browsers or imported by Excel and so on

The XmlDocument doesn't perform any validation on the data that you send it, it leaves that to you (the developer). This XML document should be invalid in almost every thing that uses XML (but I could be wrong about that ... you could always test it :P)

Almost every time I've hit this problem, I ended up using replacing the offending XML data with either the proper character (if it has one) or just getting rid of it.

You could also try putting your xml inside a CData block, but that will bloat the file a tiny bit (not sure how big overall your file will be)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this [xml parse error on illegal character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136954/xml-parse-error-on-illegal-character)

Conclusion (as I understood it):
With XML 1.0 it is impossible to store this value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer to see if it helps:

[.NET DataSet.GetXml() - what's the default encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876022/net-dataset-getxml-whats-the-default-encoding)

Comment: Thanks for your tipp, but the string I get with ds.GetXml() is internally in unicode (utf-16) I think and when writing to textfile without change of encoding everything should be ok?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you're processing a Control-Z (end of text file) character.  Is this possible?

Comment: Hm google said "reserved unused" for iso8859-1 and its superset cp1252 maybe it is end of file mark,  ... but content in DB is black box for me, so I have no possibility to filter for clean input into the DB tables ...

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to escape XML entities, eg. `& => &amp;`
Otherwise, wrap the data in CDATA http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Comment: Even as an entity, `&#x1A;`, it is still invalid.

Comment: Two problems. 1. XML and HTML entities are different things. By default XML supports only 5 entities, the rest can be defined by a DTD. &#x1A; is a HTML entity, not an XML one. So &#x1A; will not work in XML, you would need to write it as &#26;. Problem 2. as above answer suggested, non-printable characters cannot be inserted in to XML. So you will need to escape something like &#21; to &amp;#21; before it is parsed by XML.