# xml parse error on illegal character

Tags: xml, encoding

SO, I am asking as a last resort, as I am completely out of ideas.

I have a Windows ASP.NET ASMX web services app that returns a serialized Person object with a --
name, address, email... etc

but some attributes in the xml are encoded very weirdly, for instance- `&#x1a` (I dont know where the encoding takes place. I assume in the serialization process)

[googling those characters](http://www.google.com/search?q=%26%23x1a&)  I see that it is "Windows-1252" encoding.

The problem occurs during parsing of the XML, I found, a parse error of "invalid unicode character" at the position of the 1252 encoding.

how can I successfully parse it? what solutions do you suggest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parser is correct, whatever produced the serialisation is wrong. As with most of the C0/C1 control characters, it is invalid—actually, worse than that: not well-formed—to put a [U+001A SUBSTITUTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) into an XML 1.0 file(*), even if encoded as a character reference such as `&#x1A;`.

No XML parser will read this, nor should it. Whilst you could put some horrific hack in to try to filter out `&#x1A;` sequences before passing them to the parser, such crude hacks wouldn't work for the general case. The serialiser should be fixed to stop producing them.

Actually I have no idea how the character (often used to mark end-of-file in ancient horrible operating systems) would get into the dataset used by an ASP.NET app, but it wouldn't seem to play any valid role in a name, address or e-mail. Perhaps really you need to be looking at cleaning your data.

(*: It would be legal if encoded as a character reference in an XML 1.1 document. If you absolutely must round-trip control characters through XML, you will have to use XML 1.1. Though that may lead to compatibility issues with older XML parsers, and you still can't use the U+0000 NULL character, so you're never going to be completely binary-safe.)

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer -- I am presuming the data was entered as a copy paste from a word file or something of that sort.

Comment: Yeah, that would be common for the C1 control codes in the range 0x80-0x9F (typically coming from code page 1252 smart quotes mis-interpreted as ISO-8859-1), but the 0x1A control code isn't used for anything by Word, or any other common modern Windows app I can think of.

Comment: so bob, I have no control over the data how it comes to me -- is the only way to have that horrific hack and remove it from the string or is there another way to represent it --- for example before the serialization -- check if the string is UTF-8 legal.

Comment: It's not an encoding issue: character U+001A is equally invalid in UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or plain old 7-bit ASCII. You can remove the string `&#x1A;` with a simple string replace, but all attempts to handle XML with string/regex hacking risks breaking cases where it is not markup, such as in a `<!-- comment -->`, `<?pi?>` or `<![CDATA section]]>`. But you can't handle this input as XML, because with this control character in it, **it simply isn't XML**. If it is *supposed to be* XML, you need to find the party responsible for generating it and complain vociferously until they fix it.

Comment: We are seeing this &#x1A; character escape/encoding come into our web based Order Entry system (asp.net mvc 4 / WCF)   and it was from one of our specialists copy/pasting it from Outlook. In outlook it looks like a smart quote where someone was trying to indicate **inches**. It successfully saves to our database, but, when we try to select it out of SQL using CAST(theDataField as XML) we do get an error - (fwiw our DB field is not of type XML even though that's what we store in it, thus the cast that usually succeeds fails)